# I want to show a pdf icon on my tumbnail when uploading a pdf file

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I've trying to make research of it but couldn't find any solution. I'm new on javascript so maybe I'm doing something wrong on my function. I want to show a pdf icon at my thumbnail when we uploading pdf file. except from pdf it will show an images of the image that we upload Please assist me

Here are my JavaScript :

```
function readURL(input, imgno) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

        var imgPath = input.files[0].value;
        var ext = $(input).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        if ($.inArray(ext, ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'pdf']) == -1) {
            MsgBox('Message', 'Only file with extension ".jpg", ".jpeg" , ".png" , ".gif", ".pdf"  are allowed');
            
            $(input).filestyle('clear');
        } else {

            if (input.files[0].size > 1024000) {
                MsgBox("Message", "Uploaded File <b> " + input.files[0].name + "</b>  " + input.files[0].size / 1000 + "KB");
                //bootstrap_alert.warning('#sender-alert', "Uploaded File <b> " + input.files[0].name + "</b>  " + input.files[0].size / 1000 + "KB");
                'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPABAP///wAAACH5BAEKAAAA‌​LAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw%3D%3D').attr("title", "");
                $(input).filestyle('clear');
            
                return;
            }
        }
        var image_holder = $("#image-holder" + imgno);
        image_holder.empty();

        var filename = input.files[0].name;
        //var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
        //if (extn == "gif" || extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("<img />", {
                "src": e.target.result,
                "class": "thumb-image",
                "title": filename,
                "width": "100",
                "height": "100"
            }).appendTo(image_holder);
            // $(this).children('a').addClass('active').end()

            $("<button />", {
                "class": "btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-sm",
                "type": "button",
                "onclick": "ClearImage('" + imgno + "')"
            }).appendTo(image_holder);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML :

```
var base1 = string.Empty; var base2 = string.Empty; var base3 = string.Empty; var base4 = string.Empty; var base5 = string.Empty;
var imgSrc1 = string.Empty; var imgSrc2 = string.Empty; var imgSrc3 = string.Empty; var imgSrc4 = string.Empty; var imgSrc5 = string.Empty; ;

if (Model.Picture1 != null) { base1 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Picture1); imgSrc1 = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base1); }
else { base1 = "#"; }

if (Model.Picture2 != null) { base2 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Picture2); imgSrc2 = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base2); }
else { base2 = "#"; }

if (Model.Picture3 != null) { base3 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Picture3); imgSrc3 = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base3); }
else { base3 = "#"; }

if (Model.Picture4 != null) { base4 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Picture4); imgSrc4 = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base4); }
else { base4 = "#"; }

if (Model.Picture5 != null) { base5 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Picture5); imgSrc5 = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base5); }
else { base5 = "#"; }




<div class="gallery" id="gallery">
    <ul class="enlarge clearfix list-inline" id="tempenlarge">
        <li>
            <div id="image-holder1">
                <img class="img-thumbnail thumbnail-size" src='@imgSrc1' width="100" height="100" id="image1" />
                <button class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-sm" onclick="ClearImage('1')" type="button" />
            </div>
            <input id="file-1" name="uploadImages" type="file" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pdf" onchange="readURL(this, '1');" class="filestyle form-control " data-buttontext="GOV ID" data-buttonname="btn-primary" data-size="xs">
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="image-holder2">
                <img class="img-thumbnail thumbnail-size" src='@imgSrc2' width="100" height="100" id="image2" />
                <button class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-sm" onclick="ClearImage('2')" type="button" />
            </div>
            <input id="file-2" name="uploadImages" type="file" onchange="readURL(this, '2');" class="filestyle" data-buttontext="DOCUMENT 1" data-buttonname="btn-primary" data-size="xs">
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="image-holder3">
                <img class="img-thumbnail thumbnail-size" src='@imgSrc3' width="100" height="100" id="image3" />
                <button class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-sm" onclick="ClearImage('3')" type="button" />
            </div>

            <input id="file-3" name="uploadImages" type="file" onchange="readURL(this, '3');" class="filestyle" data-buttontext="DOCUMENT 2" data-buttonname="btn-primary" data-size="xs">
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="image-holder4">
                <img class="img-thumbnail thumbnail-size" src='@imgSrc4' width="100" height="100" id="image4" />
                <button class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-sm" onclick="ClearImage('4')" type="button" />
            </div>

            <input id="file-4" name="uploadImages" type="file" onchange="readURL(this, '4');" class="filestyle" data-buttontext="DOCUMENT 3" data-buttonname="btn-primary" data-size="xs">
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="image-holder5">
                <img class="img-thumbnail thumbnail-size" src='@imgSrc5' width="100" height="100" id="image5" />
                <button class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-sm" onclick="ClearImage('5')" type="button" />
            </div>

            <input id="file-5" name="uploadImages" type="file" onchange="readURL(this, '5');" class="filestyle" data-buttontext="DOCUMENT 4" data-buttonname="btn-primary" data-size="xs">

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The question is unclear.  Your code displays a thumbnail image when the file is an image type.  However, you can not display a thumbnail of a pdf file using the dataURL.  So are you asking how to display an alternate file image when the file is a pdf?  I do not understand "except from pdf it will show an images of the image that we upload " Please explain better.

Comment: yes my question is how to display an alternate file image when the file is a pdf @Yogi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer was written before OP updated the question, but the solution still applies.*

**Update**

In a comment OP asked for further assistance. After reviewing the code I found 6 fatal errors that prevent it from working. Additionally, the code requires 3 minor modifications to display the default PDF image asked for in the question. The corrected code with comments may be found here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/52ts379e/)

*The fiddle includes only the minimum changes to get the code working.*

**Problem**

We want to display thumbnail images of the files the user has selected to upload. When the file is an image type we can use the [dataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs) to display the actual image. However, we can not display a thumbnail for a PDF file in the same way. And while it is possible to generate an image from the first page of a PDF, it's a complex and lengthy process. So as a simple alternative we want to use a default thumbnail image for PDF files.

**Solution**

The file object has a type property which we can use to determine if it is an image or some other kind of file. The type value will start with "image/" for gif, png, jpg, and other images. And for a PDF it will be "application/pdf".

So using a [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) we can select the dataURL (target.result) for images or fallback to a default image for other file types. In this case we only have PDF and one default image, but it could be expanded to show different images for different file types.

```
let src = file.type.startsWith("image") ? e.target.result : defaultImage;
```

And this is the example output after selecting an image and a PDF:

[image]

**Snippet**

Unlike the original code, the snippet uses a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to display the thumbnail and metadata. However, the src variable could easily be added to OP's existing code.

```js
function readURL(input, imgno) {

  let file = input.files[0];

  // file validation code not shown

  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {

    let src = file.type.startsWith("image") ? e.target.result : defaultImage;
    let size = (file.size / 1024).toFixed(0);
    let date = new Date(file.lastModified).toLocaleDateString();
  
    $("#image-holder").append(`
      <div id="image-holder-${imgno}" class="list-group-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">
            <img src="${src}" class="thumb-image">
          </div
          <div class="col">
            <ul style="font-size:small">
              <li>Filename: ${file.name}</li>
              <li>Type: ${file.type}</li>
              <li>Size: ${size} kb</li>
              <li>Date: ${date}</li>
              <li><a href="#">Remove</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    `);

  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}



let defaultImage = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/87/PDF_file_icon.svg/833px-PDF_file_icon.svg.png";


upload.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  readURL(this, 1);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.thumb-image {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="upload" accept="application/pdf,image/*">
<hr/>
<div id="image-holder" class="list-group"></div>

<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" ></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: so did i need to change m entire javsascript?

Comment: No, you only need to make 2 small changes to your existing code to make it work like you want.  I have a meeting now, but can update the answer later to show you how if you have trouble.

Comment: I really appreciate your assistance. it seems to be having an issue, hehe. I apologise for bothering you, but it would be helpful if you could indicate where portion of my code has to be modified. I'm likewise in the learning stage.

Comment: hai sir it still didnt work at my code. i dont know why maybe i do some mistake

Comment: @Learner - see the updated answer that includes a working JSFiddle from your original code.

Comment: IT WORKING!!!!! THANKL YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP! YOU ARE MY LIFE SAVIOUR SIR! but after i refresh the page , for pdf file it still showing crash image on tumbnail

Comment: i already removed `var base1 = string.Empty;`  `var base1 = string.Empty;` and `if (Model.Picture1 != null)`  `{ base1 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Picture1);` `imgSrc1 = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base1);` `else { base1 = "#"; }` but in my html the `src =@imgScr1` could be read because its not exits

Comment: @Learner - Remove the src attribute from each image as show in this [update](https://jsfiddle.net/od3eup1b/)  The browser will only display the "crash" icon when the image has an invalid src.

Comment: done but the result its not as expected. the file all become blank. BTW i take the document from the database

Comment: @Learner - Ok, I think I understand now.  This is a .NET C# (Razor) page and you are loading gallery images from the database on the server side.  That wasn't clear as the question wasn't tagged as .NET.   So you will need to add back the C# code that populates the Modal. Then it should work as you expect.

Comment: Thank you so much! you helped me alot! Thank you so much sir! if you dont mind may i know how to increase the file size of uploading? because i try to change from 1mb into 10mb but it seem doesnt work at all